# Basic URL(string, relativeTo) doesn't output correclty

Tags: swift, string, url

i'm trying to have a final url that I can use in my application but I can't seem to find why it doesn't output correctly

```swift
var baseURL: URL = {
    return URL(string: "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/someKey/")!
}()

let url = URL(string: "test", relativeTo: baseURL)
```

The output should be:

```swift
https://api.darksky.net/forecast/someKey/test
```

but instead it's just printing me:

```swift
test -- https://api.darksky.net/forecast/someKey/
```

Comment: That is the *description* of the url. The url is correct and you can just use it. (If you need a string representation then use `url.absoluteString`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing `url.description`, *(which is the Playground preview value of `url`)* but if you look at its property `absoluteString`, you see that the created URL is indeed correct and has the expected value.

```
let baseURL = URL(string: "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/someKey/")!

let url = URL(string: "test", relativeTo: baseURL)
url?.absoluteString // "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/someKey/test"
```